# Is the universal cover of figure-8 contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, cayley-graphs

The universal cover of the figure-8 is the Cayley graph of the free group on $2$ generators with generating set $\{a,b\}$. So it is a tree. I know that finite trees are contractible. But this Cayley graph has too many edges and I don't know if I can contract this in finite time.

So my question is whether this universal cover contractible? If no why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's still contractible and the number of edges isn't a problem.

Comment: All trees are contractible. You locally contract each edge towards the origin, and then you glue all those local contractions. This can be done even if there are infinitely many edges, with a bit care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-empty locally finite tree is contractible. To see this, let $(T,d)$ be such a tree realized as a metric space, i.e. any edge has length one. Fix some $x_0 \in T$. For any $y \in T$, let $c_y : [0,1]\to T$ be the *unique* path of length 1 and constant speed connecting $x_0$ to $y$, i.e. $c_y(0)=x_0$ and $c_y(1) = y$ as well as $d(x_0, c_y(t)) = t \cdot d(x_0,y)$. Now define the following homotopy:
$$ H : T\times [0,1] \to T; \quad (y,t) \mapsto c_y(t).$$

It is continuous by uniqueness of $c_y$, and clearly $H(\cdot,1) = \operatorname{id}_T$ and $H(\cdot,0) \equiv x_0$, hence $T$ is contractible.

Comment: Careful. For that argument to be valid you need to assume that the tree is locally finite, otherwise I don't think that the geometric realization is metrisable.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. Any tree is metrizable in this way, right? We just define the metric $d(x,y)$ as length of the unique path between $x$ and $y$ for nodes and extend this to points on the edges.

Comment: That depends on the definition of "tree". It may mean "geometric realization", meaning we define the space as a disjoint union of $[0,1]$ intervals, one per edge, and then we glue common endpoints (quotient topology). This topology coincides with the metric topology when the initial graph is locally finite (i.e. each vertex has finitely many neighbours). But, as far as I remember, it is not metrizable otherwise.

Comment: Ah, right, you are correct. I will edit my answer accordingly, thank you!